# return row number when all row data is available

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe

Given a data.frame like

```
x y label
1 2 a
2 3 b
3 4 c
```

and values "2","3","b" what is the fastest way to determine the row index/number from the data.frame?

In this case the answer should be 2.

Comment: Something like `which(do.call(paste, df) == '2 3 b')`

Comment: @Sotos Thanks! Getting integer(0) as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `do.call` and `paste` as follows,

```
which(do.call(paste, df) == '2 3 b')
#[1] 2
```

However, you need to be careful as to how you are defining the string (in this case `2 3 b`). The following will clarify,

```
which(do.call(paste, c(df, sep = ',')) =='2,3,b')
#[1] 2
which(do.call(paste, c(df, sep = '_')) =='2_3_b')
#[1] 2
```

Alternatively, If you have multiple strings to check, then `match` comes in handy,

```
ind <- c('2,3,b', '3,4,c')
match(ind, do.call(paste, c(df, sep = ',')))
#[1] 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
which(!rowSums(df1!= list(2, 3, "b")))
#[1] 2
```

Or another option is `Map`

```
which(Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, df1, list(2, 3, 'b'))))
#[1] 2
```